# (la)tex-mode-hook doesn't work?

Tags: hooks

I was playing around with my .emacs, and I cannot figure out why the following does not work with .tex files:

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook
  (lambda () 
    (show-paren-mode t)))
```

On the other hand, the following does work on elisp files.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
  (lambda () 
    (show-paren-mode t)))
```

Actually, just having the elisp hook is sufficient to enable paren mode on .tex files. I'm not sure what's going on.

Running 24.5.1 on OS X with auctex installed.

Comment: Everyone who uses AUCTex gets confused between the built-in `tex-mode.el` and AUCTex which does not ship with Emacs.  The hooks that AUCTex uses are similar looking, but are different -- here is a link t the manual describing common hooks used in AUCTex:  https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Modes-and-Hooks.html

Comment: When in a .tex file, I used `M-x describe-mode`, and it stated that both tex-mode-hook and latex-mode-hook are invoked however.

Comment: But you're correct, changing `tex-mode-hook` to `LaTeX-mode-hook` made things work

Comment: I guess i missed the line `:override advice: \`TeX-latex-mode'` in `describe-mode`

Comment: BTW, instead of `(lambda () (show-paren-mode 1))` you can just write `#'show-paren-mode`.

Comment: I never understood what `#'` means. Can I omit the #?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have AUCTeX installed, then you're presumably using AUCTeX's modes, so the hooks you need to use have names of the form `TeX-mode-hook` and `LaTeX-mode-hook` (note the capitalization).